# Change style on status change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a rectangle on my view that should change its background color according to the value of a property on the view model.

```
<Rectangle DataContext="{Binding State}" />
```

**View model**

```
public class MyViewModel {

    // dummy property
    public Status State { get; private set; }

}
```

**Status**

```
public enum Status {
    State1,
    State2,
    State3
}
```

How can I hookup the rectangle on the view to the various possible states now? Is this a *EventTrigger*, *DataTrigger* or do I have to create a *ControlTemplate*? I'm only asking for the things that needs to be done on the view, the view model etc. is already working correctly and notifying the status changes.

Comment: You can use a ValueConverter in the Binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can bind `Rectangle.Fill` to `Status` through custom [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}" />
```

and converter would looks something like this:

```
public class StatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((Status)value)
        {
            case Status.State1:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            case Status.State2:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            case Status.State3:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Datatriggers should do the job of changing the rectangle background on your viewmodel status change.
Something like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="State1">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="State2">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Hope that helps